# Join in mapreduce

Tags: java, eclipse, mapreduce, guava

I am working on map reduce join problem using joiner and splitter functions. I have searched a lot on Google and finds about adding guava-18.0.jar file in the referenced libraries of the project. I also attached the javadoc location to the jar file but still getting this error mentioned below:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Splitter
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at edu.cs.okstate.cs.Partitioning.Partition_Mapper.setup(Partition_Mapper.java:29)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Comment: this is getting thrown when you try to launch the job?

Comment: Actually it says Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Splitter

Comment: can you show the command you executed?

Comment: The command that I use for running the job is:  hadoop jar Desktop/Graph_Partition.jar g_p.ReduceSideJoinDriver ilac/Partition/UserDetails.csv  ilac/Partition1 ilac/output_gp

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using your IDE to manage your project and not a dependency management tool (Maven, Gradle, Ant+Ivy...), and the Guava jar doesn't actually end up in the classpath of your Hadoop job.

Make sure it gets bundled with what's deployed.